# Editing hosts and hostname files for multiple servers

Tags: cloud-hosting

I have a cloud server running Debian 7. My domain (`www.domain.com` and `domain.com`) both have an `A` record pointing to the static IP address of my cloud server.

On the cloud server itself, what should my `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` be set as?

I plan to have multiple servers, so I started labeling the servers as:

```
web01-east 
web01-west 
sql01-east 
sql01-west
```

so that I know the location of each server.

Should the `/etc/hosts` look like:

```
web01-east
```

or

```
web01-east.domain.com
```

And should the `/etc/hostnames` look like:

```
1.1.1.1 web01-east
```

or

```
1.1.1.1 web01-east.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a clustered setup where I named my hosts in `/etc/host` as:

```
192.168.0.5    master.local
XX.XX.XX.XX    www.master.com

192.168.0.6    node01.master.local
YY.YY.YY.YY    node01.master.com

192.168.0.7    node02.master.local
ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ    node02.master.com
```

With this I have a mapping of their private IPs, using `.local` and their public facing IPs without it.  The `www.master.com` is in DNS.  The other public IPs are not in DNS.  I use this setup on AWS EC2 instances today for my Nginx clusters and it works well.  Adding a new node is then a mindless operation and a simple cluster configuration.

I use the public name (without local) as each server's hostname.

You can put pretty much anything you want in the hosts file.  The names are local to that machine anyway.  It's really how you want to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/hosts file has the entry of the server's hostname. If you wish to point a domain locally on that server you can add the entry of that domain as well.

Ideally it is a below/

127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
xx.xx.xx.xx            server.yourdomain.com server

Replace xx.xx.xx.xx with your actual server IP.